# Polymer displaying <br/> instead of a new line

Tags: polymer

I created a Polymer element that displays an address. The address contains `\n` for new lines, so I wanted to replace it with `<br/>`.

This is the template:

```
 <br/>
  {{sanitizeAddress(address)}}
 <br/>
```

This is the code for `sanitizeAddress`:

```
 sanitizeAddress: function(unsanitizedAddress) {
      var sanitizedAddr = unsanitizedAddress.replace("\n","<br/>");
      console.log("sanitizedAddr = " + sanitizedAddr);
      return sanitizedAddr;
 }
```

This is the actual output:

> FirstLine,<br/>SecondLine

This is the expected output:

> FirstLine,
> SecondLine

How can I make the `<br/>` go away and display a new line?

Answer (score 2):

By default Polymer autoescapes HTML content in your bindings to prevent you from accidentally ending up with DOM changes you didn't want. An easy way to do it is to assign an `id` to some element then when the data is available you insert it this way:

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
  <template>
    <div id="addressContainer"></div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: 'my-element',
      properties: {
        address: {
          type: String,
          observer: '_addressChanged'
        }
      },

      _addressChanged: function(newValue) {
        this.$.addressContainer.innerHTML = newValue;
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Just be careful to only do this for HTML that you trust.

Comment: Yup. This is exactly what I ended up doing. Thanks very much.